# Filter by information embedded in ID string in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, spatial-filter

I'm working with the Dynamic World data, which is organized into tile-date images. I want to filter the image collection by tile IDs (Copernicus tiles var tiles T46QCJ, T46QDJ, T46QDK, and T46QCK.

I cannot find a variable in the metadata containing the tile ID. Instead it appears in the ID of each image layer. I subset to one date (11-16-2015) using the ee.filter.inList fuction as follows:

```
var tiles = [ '20151116T043132_20151116T043131_T46QCJ', 
              '20151116T043132_20151116T043131_T46QDJ', 
              '20151116T043132_20151116T043131_T46QDK', 
              '20151116T043132_20151116T043131_T46QCK']

var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1').
                 filter(ee.Filter.inList('system:index', tiles))
```

The problem with this approach is that it calls on the tile data only for a specific date defined in the ID. Is there a way to modify the filter so that the function calls on any images that include the tile ID but for different dates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can extract the tile id from the `system:index` property, and set it as a new property by which to filter on using your desired tiles.

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/00591b3b36a567f6236a92e3826fc12f